# Convert C code to Java (divide and conquer delaunay triangulation algorithm)

Tags: java, c, algorithm, triangulation, delaunay

I found on web this algorithm http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~gl/research/comp_geom/delaunay/delaunay.html but it is written in C. Is there a way to convert it to java? Or could you suggest divide and conquer delaunay triangulation in java? I've tried Novosoft, C2J and Tangible Software Solutions, C++2Java converters but they provide very complex code(I mean that I have to do a lot of manual work to make it work). I read about mtSystems converter but I can't found it on the web to try. I'll appreciate any help with converting or with algorithm itself.

Comment: If you scrolled down to the page, you would see [this java source code](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~gl/classes/TriangulationApplet.java). It is the source code of the applet, but you can *easily* extract algorithm out of it.

Comment: @CommuSoft as you can see in applet source code description "The Triangulator - a java applet which animates some brute force
 * Delaunay triangulation algorithms".

Comment: Well both the applet and the C code show the *O(n^2)*, *O(n^3)* and *O(n^4)* algorithm. The sweepline algorithm is - as far as I know - not part of the C code.

Comment: @CommuSoft I don't need sweep line, I need divide and conquer. It's complexity is lower and also I need to do some research about parallelism.

Comment: divide and conquer is *nearly* always *O(n log n)*, *n* for processing on a certain level and *log n* for the number of levels. The same holds for [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Divide_and_conquer).

Comment: @CommuSoft Sorry, what does it mean? All I want is divide and conquer implementation, at lest, cuz I need to compare with algorithms I've already implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You can try an incremental algorithm for example from Paul Bourke:http://paulbourke.net/papers/triangulate/. Its also very fast but especially easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I've already implemented it. Divide and conquer is the only algorithm left. @Phpdevpad